# Add restriction to relation create and save with Laravel 7 Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

Can I make a restriction on the `create()` or `save()` method on a relation?

I have added this relation to my `User` class:

```
/**
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
*/
public function journals()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Journal::class);
}
```

On occasion, I have called, say

```
... $user->journals->count();
```

or

```
$user->journals()->create([
            "index" => "A",
            "title" => "A Journal"
        ]);
```

However, the rule is that you can't have more than one incomplete journal.

```
$user->journals()->create([
            "index" => "A",
            "title" => "A Journal",
            "completed_at" => null
        ]);

// this needs to fail

$user->journals()->create([
            "index" => "B",
            "title" => "Another Journal"
        ]);
```

Clearly I don't want to just have to tell people not to do it.

Extend the Illuminate class and add a preprocessor?

Comment: You can perhaps tap into eloquent Hooks and check if the field is null if a record already exist for that user, but I would say this should be part of the validation layer.

Comment: Yes, it's an event listener on `Journal::creating`